# PackageApplication fails because app does not Satisfy its Designated Requirement

Tags: ios, command-line, build, ipa

I'm having trouble packaging an app as an IPA with `PackageApplication`. Codesign verification fails with **"does not satisfy its designated Requirement"**:

```
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv -R=anchor apple generic and (certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)) /var/folders/8j/n5d5y1bj6wz3l8gs_djqn3400000gn/T/8xonyTiAuP/Payload/Planner.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 3 : [/var/folders/8j/n5d5y1bj6wz3l8gs_djqn3400000gn/T/8xonyTiAuP/Payload/Planner.app: valid on disk
/var/folders/8j/n5d5y1bj6wz3l8gs_djqn3400000gn/T/8xonyTiAuP/Payload/Planner.app: does not satisfy its designated Requirement
/var/folders/8j/n5d5y1bj6wz3l8gs_djqn3400000gn/T/8xonyTiAuP/Payload/Planner.app: explicit requirement satisfied
```

What requirement is designated here?!?

I'm building with xcodebuild:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme Planner -ask iphoneos clean build archive
```

which creates an Xcode archive for me inside `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` So far so good.

Then I've read that people use PackageApplication but that fails for me:

```
 xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v path/to/Planner.app -o Planner.ipa --sign 9990807058544973D70EA9A9F3BB3949D51C0983 --embed my_profile.mobileprovision
```

with the above error.

What part am I missing here? Is there another way to do this?

This is Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Can you successfully create an IPA from within Xcode?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can check what the designated requirements for your `.app` file are by running the following command:

```
codesign -d -r- path/to/file.app
```

Your output should include a line that starts with `designated =>`.  What follows after are your *designated requirements*.  An example of this output would be:

`designated => identifier "com.organization.project" and certificate root = H"abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef12"`

The `-d` flag displays information and the `-r-` flag writes the requirements to `stdout`.

You can use Apple's page on [Code Signing Requirement Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/RequirementLang/RequirementLang.html) to interpret what these requirements mean.

If you want to narrow down which particular requirement is failing, you can run the tests individually by entering the following command:

`codesign -v -R="certificate root = H\"abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef12\"" /path/to/file.app`

The `-v` flag performs verification on your app and the `-R` flag passes in an explicit requirement to test.